# Why is my code not working properly?

Tags: java, selenium, testing

Here is my code:

```
try {
     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
     Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());

      //Accepting alert.
      alert.accept();
      System.out.println("Accepted the alert successfully.");
   } catch(Throwable e) {
      System.err.println("Error came while waiting for the alert popup. "+e.getMessage());
   }
```

The error is showing like:

> Error came while waiting for the alert popup. Expected condition failed: waiting for alert to be present (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

Comment: Need to check in your page that it's javascript alert or not???

Comment: sir, thanks for the reponse. its a javascript alert message , its a window based i think autoit tool is useful for that.. whats your opinon? tell me imediately? waiting for the response..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it is not necessary to wait for alert. You can use the normal code like

```
  Alert alert = webDriver.switchTo().alert();
```

Try this out.
PS: This Alert class can handle alert boxes by javascript only, check if your alert is not made of any html elements

Comment: thanks for the repose .. what is your opinion about autoit tool?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use the following code.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
try{
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
}
catch (Exception e)
    System.out.println("No alert");
```